# Error when inserting int value in sqlite table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I insert the `int` value in my sqlite it keeps saying returning `false`

Here is My `onCreate` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table PicTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,pic_key INTEGER)");
}
```

and this is the method for checking the insert

```
 public boolean insertPic (int pic){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("pic_key",pic);
    long result = db.insert("PicTable",null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

When I input the `int` value it returns `false`

Is there an error in my code or something?

this is my logcat

```
02-21 03:14:35.916 4507-4507/com.example.android.durak E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting pic_key=1
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PicTable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO PicTable(pic_key) VALUES (?)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                             at com.example.android.durak.sql_lite.insertPic(sql_lite.java:64)
                                                                             at com.example.android.durak.Option.Save(Option.java:33)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: show your logcat..

Comment: [mcve] please. Where are you calling this method? How are you checking "nothing" is returned? Note: ID Column should be named `_id` for matching Android conventions

Comment: i puted my logcat

Comment: you can see the wrong

Comment: Could you be running into a case-sensitivity problem?  Try using "pictable" iso. "PicTable".   Or else "create table `PicTable`"  (with PicTable between reverse quotes).

Comment: Likely your device has a previously created database file that does not have the table. You can uninstall and reinstall your app to get rid of the old database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run